# importing JSON file from google drive in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-drive-shared-drive

I am working on app to import a lit from **google drive** in the form of JSON file, the App will read the JSON file only, *the reason is I am not using Firestore Database is because it delays the build of the App & whatever I tried still I have errors & I can't build the APP on IOS device or simulator*, so every time I will try to import the data the App will show error. my code is as the following

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Samer'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
        future: UsersApi.getApps(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final users = snapshot.data;
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Center(child: Text('error'));
              } else {
                return buildUsers(users!);
              }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildUsers(List<User> users) => ListView.builder(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: users.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final user = users[index];

          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Container(
              color: kOurAppsMainScreenCards,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(user.appName),
                // leading: CircleAvatar(
                //   backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.imageName),
                // ),
                // subtitle: Platform.isIOS
                //     ? Text(user.paidFreeIOS)
                //     : Text(user.paidFree),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
}
```

and I am using http package as following:

```
class UsersApi {
  static Future<List<User>> getApps() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tAxO2kRD0NVBhefA3srbj1SKQ2l8u9Wc/view?usp=sharing');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final body = json.decode(response.body);
    return body.map<User>(User.fromJson).toList();
  }
}
```

the stage thing is I inserted the same JSON file in firestore storage and the App read it....
Can somebody please help me.
Regards,

Comment: first you have to download this file then you will be able to read. Best way is to put this file in AWS S3, then use the public S3 URL of uploaded file then the same code will work. Make sure after hitting the URL in browser it is giving the proper output.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a way to use the google drive JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this, the main issue is in the link itself, we have to do some modification to the link & then we can use it freely, for example:
if this is the file link, we will use the bold lines in the modified link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-T9OTLTZXTB7ydqV3tcgG4T2FQckMooB/view?usp=sharing
and we have to add few words to make the link workable 100%,
the following code to be added

```
uc?export=view&id=
```

the new link will be
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1-T9OTLTZXTB7ydqV3tcgG4T2FQckMooB

Solution ref (it was for photos but it worked in JSON files also)
https://youtu.be/0ZHqrf0mzrI